# D3.js: Show escaped line breaks from a csv file

Tags: javascript, html, css, csv, d3.js

A csv file looks like this:

```
letter,frequency,description
A,.08167,single line 
B,.01492,"here you are, comma works
but this text is still a one-liner"
C,.02780,and another single one
D,.04253,and another single one
```

So, there's three cols with four rows. Thanks to the quotation marks the comma ("... here you are, ...") is escaped. This works fine.

However, this is not the case for the line break.

I'm using [d3-tip](https://github.com/Caged/d3-tip).

Full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: orange;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: orangered ;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.d3-tip {
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

/* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
.d3-tip:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Style northward tooltips differently */
.d3-tip.n:after {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(formatPercent);

var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return d.description;
  })

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.call(tip);

d3.csv("d3-tip.csv", type, function(error, data) {
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Frequency");

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); })
      .on('mouseover', tip.show)
      .on('mouseout', tip.hide)

});

function type(d) {
  d.frequency = +d.frequency;
  return d;
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`d3.csv` **is** keeping your line break, that's not the problem.

I'd guess the problem is that you're not defining the [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/white-space?v=example) properly in your CSS:

> The white-space property is used to describe how whitespace inside the element is handled.

Have a look at the two following snippets.

This is an example **without** setting the white-space:

```js
var csv = d3.csvParse(d3.select("#csv").text());

d3.select("body").selectAll("foo")
  .data(csv)
  .enter()
  .append("p")
  .html(d => d.description)
```

```css
pre {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<pre id="csv">letter,frequency,description
A,.08167,single line 
B,.01492,"here you are, comma works
but this text is still a one-liner"
C,.02780,and another single one
D,.04253,and another single one</pre>
```

Now the very same code, setting the `white-space`:

```js
var csv = d3.csvParse(d3.select("#csv").text());

d3.select("body").selectAll("foo")
  .data(csv)
  .enter()
  .append("p")
  .html(d => d.description)
```

```css
pre {
  display: none;
}

p {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<pre id="csv">letter,frequency,description
A,.08167,single line 
B,.01492,"here you are, comma works
but this text is still a one-liner"
C,.02780,and another single one
D,.04253,and another single one</pre>
```

You can see that the line break is there.

That being said, find the class that tooltip (which is `d3-tip`) and set its `white-space` properly in the CSS:

```
.d3-tip {
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 12px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

PS: I'm using a HTML `<pre>` to store your CSV instead of a real CSV file, which i cant use in the Stack snippet.

Comment: As always a huge help. Thanks a lot!